# Asp.Net Ajax Accordion

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, objectdatasource

I have two problems:

1. I am trying to connect a form view that is inside the content section of an accordion. I choose my ObjectDataSource, configure it and drop it on the page with the designer. When I switch back to the code view there is no code at all for the ObjectDataSource connection. When I run the page the form view displays no data whatsoever. I even told the accordion that the datasource ID was Object DataSource and it errors out saying that it doesn't exist! Why is this happening?
2. I need to click a button and dynamically create a new accordion pane with a blank form view that can be filled out and update the database. Theoretically I need to be able to create as many new forms as needed. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @James Johnson you forgot the spelling error in "Accordion" :)

Comment: @tsar: Thank you. Think I corrected all of them.

Comment: lol. i'm afraid not - left out the main one - in the topic. it's crucial as it's one of the main things how people could find this question, hence needs to be correct.